# Is it possible to add proguard rules dynamically by Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, proguard

Is it possible to add proguard rules to the proguard file dynamically via Gradle?

Any help is highly appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Gradle uses Groovy which means you can open ProGuard setting file to modify it when building, something along the line of:

```
def proguardFile = file("path/to/proguard/")
def proguardText = proguardFile.getText()
//modify proguardText here
proguardFile.write(proguardText)
```

Comment: Be aware of a couple things with this approach: One, know that the build script will be executed more often that when you do builds; Android Studio will run it for its own purposes, e.g. when it syncs. Two, pay attention to what build phase your code runs in; it may not do what you expect.

Comment: @ScottBarta great comment, I was definitely caught off guard by how my gradle script was run when I first work with it.

Comment: does there are some ways to add rules but make not any modifications?

Answer (score 0):

after examine the source code, I found a trick to add my proguard file during runtime without any modifications for my project file, it's achieved by java reflection, depends on your `android-plugin` version, may no available in your project.

you can check the code in my demo project:

https://github.com/vince-styling/GradleDependenciesGather